# Arrays.getOnlyElement()?

Tags: java, guava

Is there any equivalent to [Collections.getOnlyElement()](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getOnlyElement%28java.lang.Iterable%29) that works with arrays?

I'm aware it's a trivial function to implement, but Collections.getOnlyElement() is as well, and it's in guava.

Comment: Getting the only element stored in an array is simply `myArray[0]`. Is there something remarkable about your array that would require more than that?

Comment: @Votey - Yes, adding the check if (myArray.length != 1) throw new RuntimeException(...)

Comment: If that happens I guess myArray is null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.forArray(array))`

By using `Iterators.forArray`, you can bypass the need to create a copy of this array as a list, and instead iterate over the array itself. Then use `Iterators.getOnlyElement` to get the first element from an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Not nice but still a one-liner:

```
Object x = Iterables.getOnlyElement(Arrays.asList(t));
```

Comment: I wouldn't convert it to a list just for this, not worth it.

Comment: @ripper234 I think the garbage collector can handle one additional object.

Comment: @ripper234: In case you aren't aware, `Arrays.asList` doesn't copy the input array, it just creates a `List` view of it.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest we'll get.

Comment: Then again @Ray's answer has some minor perf advantage, and is equally clean.

Comment: Well, to be fair, as ColinD points out, this is really doing the same thing. `Arrays.asList` just returns a List that wraps the iterator returned by `Iterators.forArray`. Don't think you're going to see a performance difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(myArray != null && myArray.length == 1)
      return myArray[0]
```

Btw. an array can be non-null and have 0 length if initialized like this:

```
 MyType[] myArr = new MyType[0];
```

Comment: Not good, the semantic requires throwing an exception if the array is not of length 1. I didn't ask how to implement this, I know the implementation is trivial ... I asked if it's implemented anywhere.

Comment: I don't think so since arrays are kind of a legacy concept from the times before OOP. I guess the best solution is to define such a method yourself somewhere in a Helper class if you need it to throw an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any library method that does this.  It seems too simple to be worth the effort.

The closest I've come across (after trawling pages of search results) is this - [`uk.org.retep.util.collections.ArrayUtils.getFirst`](http://reteptools.kenai.com/api/retepTools/SNAPSHOT/uk/org/retep/util/collections/ArrayUtils.html#getFirst%28T%5B%5D%29) - which has a different semantic to what you are asking for.

Comment: Why is Collections.getOnlyElement() to "too simple to be worth the effort"?

Comment: @ripper234 - that's a good question.  All I can say is that if someone *does* think this is worth the effort to do, they are either lazy, or they are hiding their code somewhere that is hard to find.